# Getting rendered HTML with MozRepl and Mechanize::Firefox

Tags: perl, firefox, gwt, mechanize, mozrepl

I've just been introduced to the wonders of MozRepl used in conjunction with Perl's WWW::Mechanize::Firefox, and was trying to figure out how to use it to crawl GWT pages (e.g.,: https://www.google.com/offers/home#!details/4bc7fd6bd3feb311/XYW81TXGLA88TR42)

What I really want is the rendered html, not the actual html. Would really appreciate an example of how I would get this.

Comment: Looks like I can render the parts of the page just by doing e.g.,: $mech->xpath('//*[@id="goh-content-container"]', one=>1)->{innerHTML};   Strangely tho, this doesn't seem to consistently work. Occasionally it will output nothing, and other times it will output the HTML. Any ideas on why it's not consistently providing output?

Comment: More info: when I run a single crawler it seems to output consistently, but if I have multiple interacting with MozRepl, the output seems to be produced less consistently. Running on Ubuntu 11.04 with Firefox 7.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to use the fantastic [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to get the job done. It's incredibly easy to use Phantom as a server side tool to get the rendered HTML of a dynamic webpage.